# V-if value condition in table

Tags: vue.js

I have a table with tbody and using Vuejs:

```
 <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item,i) in data" :key="i">
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>{{item.dwg}}</td>
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.ValueOfDay1}}</td>
          <td>{{item.ValueOfDay2}}</td>
          <td>{{item.ValueOfDay3}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want to use v-if to change the styling of the `<td>` element:

```
if item.ValueOfDay1 = 10 --> background-color of <td> is red,
if item.ValueOfDay1 = 10.1 --> background-color of <td> is blue,
if item.ValueOfDay1 = 10.2 --> background-color of <td> is green.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is resolution for your problem, I hope that help you

https://jsfiddle.net/mathmelo/fjs9x7by/3/#

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    ...
    <td :class="changeBackgroundColor(item.ValueOfDay1)" >{{item.ValueOfDay1}}</td>
    ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Vue

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [
      {dwg: 0, name: 'test' , ValueOfDay1: 10, ValueOfDay2: 20, ValueOfDay3: 30},
      {dwg: 0, name: 'test2' , ValueOfDay1: 10.2, ValueOfDay2: 20, ValueOfDay3: 30},
      {dwg: 0, name: 'test3' , ValueOfDay1: 10.1, ValueOfDay2: 20, ValueOfDay3: 30}

    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changeBackgroundColor(valueOfDay) {
      //Get the decimal part of the number 
      decimals = valueOfDay - Math.floor(valueOfDay);

      switch(decimals.toFixed(1)){
        case '0.0' : return 'red'
        case '0.1' : return 'blue'
        case '0.2' : return 'green'

      }
    }
  }
});
```

And CSS

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding dynamic styling based on condition as below->
 :class="item.ValueOfDay1 == 10 ? 'bgRed' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.1 ? 'bgBlue' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.2 ? 'bgGreen' : ''"

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item,i) in data" :key="i">
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>{{item.dwg}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td :class="item.ValueOfDay1 == 10 ? 'bgRed' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.1 ? 'bgBlue' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.2 ? 'bgGreen' : ''">{{item.ValueOfDay1}}</td>
      <td :class="item.ValueOfDay1 == 10 ? 'bgRed' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.1 ? 'bgBlue' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.2 ? 'bgGreen' : ''">{{item.ValueOfDay2}}</td>
      <td :class="item.ValueOfDay1 == 10 ? 'bgRed' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.1 ? 'bgBlue' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.2 ? 'bgGreen' : ''">{{item.ValueOfDay3}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

CSS

```
.bgRed{
  background:red;
}
.bgBlue{
  background:blue;
}
.bgGreen{
  background:green;
}
```

Comment: If i have multiple values not only 10; ex.:if ValueOfday ==xx -->background-color ->red, if ValueOfDay ==xx.01 -->background-color->blue, if ValueOfDay==xx.02->background-color->green....How is code>

Comment: That's what is checked with the ternary condition. :class="item.ValueOfDay1 == 10 ? 'bgRed' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.1 ? 'bgBlue' : item.ValueOfDay1 == 10.2 ? 'bgGreen' : ''".

Comment: Above will check if value is 10/10.1/10.2 and will set that class accordingly.

Comment: Can i check: item.ValueOfDay1-Math.round(item.ValueOfDay1,0), if =0 -->red, if =0.1 -->blue, if =0.2 ->green ?

Comment: Yes you may use round function as above.